# Problems with Software Center and Terminal

Tags: command-line, software-center

Here's the problem.

When I open Software Center it's black and closes after few seconds, can't do anything. And the problem with the terminal:

```
sandro@sandro-E6224:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for sandro: 
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fehler!
E: Lesefehler - read (5: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler)
E: Die Paketliste oder die Statusdatei konnte nicht eingelesen oder geöffnet werden.
sandro@sandro-E6224:~$
```

I can't do anything. When I try to install something it loads to 4% or 97% and the text up here.

---

The errors according to Google Translate:

```
E: Read error - read (5: Input / output error)
E: The package lists or status file could not be read or opened.
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably malformed files. Just delete the files and update:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -f
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I copy paste it and the following message came up rm: das Entfernen von »/var/lib/apt/lists/partial“ ist nicht möglich: Ist ein Verzeichnis

Comment: sorry, it failed because there is a directory there (I guess, I don't read german or whatever the language is). So try what I posted now.

Comment: nope nothing... software center still not function..